# Linq where statement one to many

Tags: c#, linq

Table "aaa" have a column with foreign key to table "bbb" that in turn have it to table "ddd". Table "ddd" have a column with an ID called "costRef"

I want to select those "aaa" that have any of my "ddd" with a specific costRef that my list contains.

```
var query =
        from tr in db.aaa
        where tr.bbb.Any(x => x.ccc.ddd.Any(y => intList.Contains(y.costRef)))
        select tr;
```

In that case above I got all of my "aaa" if any have that ref. I can understand that, but it's not what I want :) But How do I manage to do this?
Tried allot with select and where statements instead of my "any". Proberly that's the way to do it but I cant manage it.

Comment: Please add your model to your question. I can't tell the property types you have from your code.

Comment: That query provides *exactly* what you described as wanting.  If it's not what you want then you need to explain how it differ from what you *do* want.

Comment: Then what do you want exactly?

Comment: What is `ccc` in your query?

Comment: In your description you introduce tables aaa, bbb and ddd, but in your code sample you introduce table ccc. What's the relation of ccc with the other tables ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion about the names. Actually thought it were easier without my long names. Anyway got my linq solved as i wanted! Were on the right track. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -2):

I did SQL before Linq was around, so I still tend to follow the same structure. In this case you could just do:

```
var query = from a in db.aaa
join b in db.bbb on a.FK equals b.ID
join c in db.ccc on b.FK equals c.ID
where intList.Contains(c.costRef)
select a
```

Comment: That is going to be a functionally equivalent query to what the OP has, except that yours is more verbose than his.

Comment: Essentially, yes it is the same (except for the ccc interference), but his solution is not working so there must be something incorrect there. This solution answers the question: I want to select those "aaa" that have any of my "ddd" with a specific costRef that my list contains.

Comment: So your query does the exact same thing as his query, and his query doesn't return what he wants.  Therefore it follows that your query won't return what he wants either.  Writing the same query slightly differently won't suddenly make it work.